# Removing Items From Panel on a Timer

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

## Background

I have a table of items that the user can edit. They can navigate through the fields with the arrow keys, and the information in the current row is saved when they move to a new one. The project requires a notification be displayed to the user when the row was successfully saved, and my boss requires me to do this through Bootstrap alerts.

One alert needs to be created for each successful save, and if the user saves multiple rows in a short time they should stack inside of a panel. Because the number of alerts is unknown, I'm dynamically adding them to the page from the code-behind. Each alert is made up of a panel and a label, which is being added to a larger panel that holds all the alerts. This part I've got figured out -- the alerts show up when they're supposed to, and in the correct numbers.

The problem is that each alert is only supposed to show on the screen for a limited amount of time. This is somewhere between two and five seconds, to be determined by my boss at a later date. My idea was to start a timer for two seconds each time an alert is created, and remove the first alert from the panel when the timer finished. Because no two timers would be created at exactly the same time, this should theoretically remove each alert two seconds after it appears, stopping once the last alert is gone. Unfortunately for me, that isn't how it's working.

Instead, I get an 'index out of bounds' exception, indicating that the alert I'm trying to remove doesn't actually exist. But it does exist -- I can see it on my screen. So I'm not sure what's going wrong.

## Code

### Creation of Alerts

This code is inside of Page_Load, so that the alerts are still visible on postback.

```
if (Session["success"] != null)
{
    int test = Convert.ToInt32(Session["success"]);
    for(int a = 1; a <= test; a++)
    {
        Panel alert = new Panel();
        alert.CssClass = "alert alert-success";
        alert.ID = "dynamicAlert" + a;
        alert.Attributes["role"] = "alert";

        Label innerAlert = new Label();
        innerAlert.ID = "dynamicAlertInner" + a;
        innerAlert.Text = "<strong>Success!</strong> Your row was saved.";
        alert.Controls.Add(innerAlert);
        alertsUpdate.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("pnlAlerts").Controls.Add(alert);
        System.Timers.Timer time = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
        time.Elapsed += removeAlert;
        time.Start();
     }

 }
```

### Deletion of Alerts

The removeAlert method is intended to remove the alert at index 0 from the panel contained within the update panel.

```
private void removeAlert(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Panel pnl = (Panel)alertsUpdate.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("pnlAlerts");
    if(pnl != null && pnl.Controls.Count > 0)
    {
        pnl.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```